# Hi, I am trying to find all the words in a text that appear only once in UNIX. What can i do differently?

Tags: shell-script

```
# -- Q2 --
# Write a pipeline that finds the number of words in the book that have been used only once.
# Your pipeline should be case insensitive
echo "-- Q2 --"
onlyOnce=$(cat *txt | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | tr -s '[:punct:][:space:]' ' '| tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq -ic | awk '$1 == 1 {print $2}')
echo "Words used only once:"
echo "$onlyOnce"
```

Comment: Are you really using UNIX or do you mean Linux? This matters because the tools available on UNIX and Linux systems are different.

Comment: Advice to newcomers: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark (✓) next to it and optionally also up-vote it (up-voting requires at least 15 reputation points). If you found other answers helpful, please up-vote them. Accepting and up-voting helps future readers. See [the relevant help-center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
cat *txt |
    tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' |
    tr -s '[:punct:][:space:]' |
    awk '{a[$1]++}END{for (i in a) if (a[i] == 1) {print i}}'
```

In your example, you can't do

```
cat files | ... | awk '{}' file
    ^^^^^                  ^^^^
```

You have to specify file(s) only one time.